# Vega-lite - remove selection when out of chart bounds

Tags: vega, vega-lite

Is it possible to cancel/empty a selection when the mouse is moved out of the chart area?

You can see an example of this "issue" on the official example here: https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/interactive_multi_line_label.html

When the page first loads, the ruler and data point marks are not visible:

[image]

Hovering over the chart and then moving the mouse away from the chart results in:

[image]

Is it possible for the chart to be returned to it's default state when the mouse is moved away from the chart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Add the [clear](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/clear.html) property to the label marker, as below:

```
"selection": {
      "label": {
        "type": "single",
        "nearest": true,
        "on": "mouseover",
        "encodings": [
          "x"
        ],
        "clear": "mouseout",
        "empty": "none"
      }
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. For others coming across this answer, please note that this  functionality only starts working in vegaLite 3.2.0 and above.